# Laravel index page and directories

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner for laravel. And I have a problem about folder indexing.

When I paste all laravel files to localhost/l4 folder. Than I go to "localhost/l4" page and there's only folder indexes in my screen. Not "welcome" page.

[image: image of indexes]

What should I do? When I paste files which are in public folder, to main folder. There's an other error as:

> Warning:
>   require(/home/movingto/public_html/or/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/movingto/public_html/or/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/movingto/public_html/or/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/movingto/public_html/or/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

I need some help please. Just wanna get laravel folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should go to `localhost/14/public` to visit the welcome page.

Second, if you apply changes to the folder places, you should as well update your `bootstrap/paths.php` file or `index.php` to proper paths (`index.php` is the basic loader of the bootstrap file and thus is superbly important)

What you can do to eliminate the `../public/..` from your address when you upload your site?

Move all of Laravel's directories and files, except public directory, to the one directory behind the `public_html`, which is `homedir/`. Then, copy the content of the public folder right into the public_html(not the public folder, just the content), and delete the public folder. You now should tell laravel about the changes, so, go to `index.php` and bootstrap/paths.php and change the path(s) to new one(s).

Answer (score 0):

Well! You can also use the Artisan command for that the command is
" PHP artisan serve ". You don't need to live with that URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).